# Algebraic morphism as nontrivial topological embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, knot-theory

According to [this article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF02566217.pdf), every knot  can be realized as the intersection of $2$ non-singular algebraic sets in $\Bbb{R}^4$, one of which is a standard $\Bbb{S}^3$. However this result use many ambient conditions, so I want to know if these conditions can be restricted, namely:

**Does there exist an algebraic morphism from $\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}^1$ to $\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}^3$ that is a topological embedding but not isotopic to the standard line in $\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}^3$?**

and a question of opposite direction:

**Is every smooth embedding from $\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}^1$ to $\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}^3$ isotopic to the image of an algebraic morphism from $\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}^1$ to $\Bbb{R}\Bbb{P}^3$?**

A complex version can also be stated by replacing $\Bbb{R}$ with $\Bbb{C}$. Due to the rigidity of complex structures, this version probably has a negative answer but I can not prove it.

Comment: In case this might help, here's another paper along the lines of Akbulut-King that gives an explicit construction from a braid presentation: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.06328

Comment: @KyleMiller I can not see the relationship between my question and this paper - it still considers $\Bbb{S}^3$ to be the unit sphere in $\Bbb{C}^2$, which is what I called "extrinsic".

Comment: I thought that it might be possible to modify the explicit construction they give to create algebraic morphisms that might answer your first question -- I have not thought carefully about this, so sorry if this this is an unhelpful suggestion.

Comment: Let me just point out that #1 is not so hard to find examples of. The $(p,q)$ torus knot can be given by the parametrization $[r\cos(p\theta):r\sin(p\theta):-\sin(q\theta):1]$ where $r=\cos(q\theta)+2$, and expanding multiple angle formulas as polynomials in $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ plus the fact that if $\Bbb RP^1$ has coordinates $[a:b]$, we may write $\cos\theta=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}$ and $\sin\theta=\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}$, we see that all torus knots can be algebraically embedded. So any torus knot which isn't an unknot provides an example.